# How can -9 % 7 be either -2 or 5?

Tags: c, modulo

Modulo as far as I understand is defined to be:

```
Floor(a/b)*b + a%b = a
```

*'a' can be +9 or -9*
so:

```
Floor(9/-7)*-7 + a%b = 9 gives a%b = 2
or
Floor(-9/7)*7 + a%b = -9 gives a%b = -2
```

How is it 5?

Comment: `Floor(-9/7)` is -2. `-2 * 7` is `-14`. What do you add to `-14` to get `-9`?

Comment: Your title refers to both `%` and “modulo”. In C, `%` is not the modulo operation. It is the **remainder** of the division operation `/` (which rounds towards zero since C99).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Only from C99 onwards. Before that, it was unspecified, and some implementations rounded down, while others rounded towards zero. (As you've now included in your comment.) So `a/b` could give either -1 or -2 if a is -9, and b is 7, and `a%b` could give either -2 or 5, but you're right, it's the remainder, so the rounding had to be consistent between `/` and `%`, and `(a/b)*b + (a%b)` had to equal `a`.

Comment: @hvd I have already edited my comment. Before C99, it was **implementation-defined** how division rounded.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I noticed :)

Comment: well, if you take programming out of the question, then `-2 === 5 (mod 7)`. this is called congruence and is a key aspect of mathematics

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin And now you take programming back again, and we've got RSA. It seems that this kind of "subtract x and then add x" trick not only works in algebra :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is what is going on:
Floor(-9/7) can be rounded off upwards or downwards. Therefore: -1.285.. can be rounded to either -1 or -2. If its rounded to -1, then a%b is -2 but if you round to -2, then a%b = 5 because Floor(-9/7)*7 + a%b = -9; which gives -2*7 + a%b = -9; which gives 5.

In other words the direction of rounding off the floor value of -1.285.. has to be factored in because different hardware architectures rounded differently some towards the top(-1) and others towards the bottom (-2 which is more negative).

> The C89 standard states that if either operand is negative. the result
>   of a divi- sion can be rounded either up or down.
>
> In C99. on the other hand. the result of a division is always
>   truncated toward zero (so - 9 / 7 has the value -I) and the value of i
>   % j has the same sign as i (hence the value of -9 96 7 is -2).

**% is the remainder operator.**

Comment: -9/7 isn't  -1.285, it's -1, since it's an integer division